# Probability that the distance to diagonal of a square is less than $\dfrac{\sqrt2}2$?

Tags: probability

A point $P$ is picked at random in the square $ABCD$, with sides of length $1$. what is the probability that the distance from $P$ to diagonal $AC$ is less than $\dfrac{\sqrt2}2$?

I think the answer is $\dfrac{1}2$ but also i think the probability is 1

my answer: $\dfrac{2*\dfrac{\sqrt2}2*\dfrac{\sqrt2}2*\dfrac{1}2}2$ but i think any point be picked is less than $\dfrac{\sqrt2}2$ distance to diagonal of a square so the probability is 1

Comment: Welcome to MSE! You'll find that people are very helpful here if you show that you've made an effort.

Comment: @Remy Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 1):

Your second answer is correct. The furthest a point could be from  $AC$ is $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ when $P$ is at $B$ or $D$.

Hence, the desired probability is $1$.